# Is it possible to make a copolymer using Rice wax and Sebacic acid?

Tags: polymers

I would like to make a copolymer using Sebacic Acid, however I dont know which process of polymerization is required and which other monomer can be used, I would like to use Rice Wax or rice bran wax.

Is this possible to do?

[Edit]

It seems that rice bran wax is not suitable to produce a copolymer with sebacic acid - I am now in search of a naturally derived oil or wax that with polymerize with sebacic acid.

Comment: oils and waxes by definition are esters that would largely be unsuitable for polymerization with a diacid. There a a few relatively rare dihydroxylated fatty acids found in some oils and waxes, but you would have a hard time isolating enough to be useful. You would have to chemically convert a fatty acid into a diol, which may or may not fit your definition of "naturally derived"

Answer (score 4):

Sebacic acid is a diacid, so the common compounds used to make a polymer with it are diamines (to make a polyamide) and diols (to make a polyester). Rice bran wax is composed of monoacids, so it is not going to make a polymer with sebacic acid.

The best known polymer using sebacic acid is made with 1,5-pentanediamine (aka cadaverine) and is known as nylon 5,10.

Comment: Thanks for the answer andrew, in this case is it possible to use another oil such as jojoba oil as the diol?

Comment: @RohamC no, jojoba oil is not composed of diols.

Comment: Thanks again for your insight Andrew. The reason I ask this is because I have come across a product that claims it is a copolymer used to seal the structure of broken hair. Now this is something im trying to achieve too and im looking for possible oils/waxes that would make a similar product. The one I came across was a copolymer made from hydrogenated castor oil and sebacic acid.... As Im reading more about these compounds I have even more questions so I do appreciate your knowledge... if you know of any naturally occuring oils that could be used to create copolymers then please let me know!